# Jittery navigation bar animation while hide native view

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I want to show native view inside/(at the end of view) my flutter view. Thinking of hide native view while I push to other flutter view. To hide native I am setting it's height to zero, by calling a function through flutter channel, but the animation to set the height is not smooth as it should be, please check my attached [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wr5mo9vf5ooff8m/flutter%20native%20view%20animatioin.mov?dl=0) and POC [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7y8dg520eq0bhu/native_view.zip?dl=0).

[image]

In iOS I had edited the default storyboard like following screenshot 
[image]- Taken a main storyboard with two container views flutterviewcontroller and nativeViewController respectively.

Comment: Any chance you can upload the video using imgur's image to gif function? Dropbox is a no go for me.

Comment: @F-1 please check my edited question.

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest version? I noticed much performance improvement, after performing the `flutter upgrade`...

Comment: @dzim yes I did, in which channel I must have ?, I am in beta now.

Comment: Hm. I think I'm on Beta, as well...